# How to rethrow DmlExceptions as AuraHandledExceptions right

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, exception, dmlexception, adderror

Exception handling in Lightning is a pain. Instead of Lightning showing regular exceptions one has to catch them in code and rethrow them as `AuraHandledExceptions` as shown below:

```
try {
    ....
    update records;
}
catch(DmlException ex) {
    throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Especially in cases of `DmlExceptions` that can contain multiple errors (one per record) the output is more than ugly:

[image]

**My questions:**

1. How can I just show the message of the **original first error** (the blurry part in my screenshot without all the techie stuff in front of it?
2. How can I train AuraHandledException to show a nice title not **ApexActionError**?
3. Is there any **technical reason** for requiring to rethrow exceptions for Lightning? And is there a roadmap to make this more convenient.

Comment: According to this documentation -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm you can get more specific error message per each row, f.e.   ex.getDmlMessage(0)

Comment: This challenge never occured to us since we always use a DTO between Apex and lightning. The DTO stores error/success and corresponding messages as well.

Comment: I found out that we can customize title. showToast event has `title` parameter and we can set it.

Answer (score 5):

I just directly rethrow `DMLException`. They are actually handled properly by the framework. So, my error handling often looks like this:

```
    try {
        upsert value;
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

If there is a `DMLException`, it arrives in Lightning as a structured error object where you can split those errors up into multiple message if you want to.

It would be nice if `AuraHandledException` had more methods so that we could add structure to custom errors, but I can't find any ability to do that.

Comment: This means when I just expect a DmlException I don't need to have a try catch at all? Didn't work. The message didn't make it to the UI. And rethrowing it is not much more elegant.

Comment: Are you talking about a Lightning Apex controller here? Or triggers that run when users are working through LEX in the standard UI. I was assuming the former, but maybe you mean the latter?

Comment: It are triggers that do addError on multiple record.

Comment: In that sense, it's just like Classic, isn't it? If your trigger causes an unhandled exception when it's doing DML, you end up with an ugly error in the UI.