# How to show exception message in lightning without stacktrace?

Tags: apex, lightning

**Background:**

1. I have trigger on `Opportunity` object for `after delete` event and it updates a field `Number_of_Opps__c` on `Account` object.
2. There is a validation rule on `Account` object for the same field firing if `Number_of_Opps__c = 0`
3. When I am deleting Opportunity record from custom lightning component,trigger on Opportunity is running and it is updating field `Account.Number_of_Opps__c` to zero but validation rule on Account object is rejecting this update.

**Problem:**
When this happens, I need to show user a simple and clean message without stacktrace of trigger line number.

**My observation:**

1. If Apex trigger is not involved then it is displaying clean message to the user without stacktrace of line numbers.

I have gone through [Error Handling Best Practices for Lightning and Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html) but no luck.

As a last resort, I have tried to use regex to replace everything after `: []` and even that is not working, maybe something wrong with my regex.

Here is the code:

**HelloWorld.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="HelloWorldApexController">
    <button onclick="{!c.delete}">Delete</button>
</aura:component>
```

**HelloWorldController.js:**

```
({
    delete: function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.deleteOpp");
        action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
            if(result.getState() == 'SUCCESS'){

            }
            if(result.getState() == 'ERROR'){
                var toast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                if(toast){
                    toast.setParams({
                        "title": "Error",
                        "message": result.getError()[0].message
                    });
                }
                toast.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**HelloWorldApexController.cls:**

```
public with sharing class HelloWorldApexController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void deleteOpp(){
        Opportunity oppObj = new Opportunity(Id='006370000025PVY');

        try{
            delete oppObj;  
        }catch(DmlException e){
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getDmlMessage(0).replaceFirst(': \\[\\] .*',''));
        }
    }
}
```

**OpportunityTrigger.trigger:**

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after delete) {

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isDelete){
        Account accObj = new Account(Id = '00137000002KXpBAAW',Number_of_Opps__c = 0);
        update accObj;
    }

}
```

**Note:** For the sake of simplicity, I have hardcoded Ids and did not bulkify the trigger.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Honestly, you're asking about the wrong problem. You should be designing each trigger in a way that will absolutely only ever use addError and not throw an exception. It's 100% possible to do this 100% of the time. Learning how to write proper triggers is essential.

Comment: @sfdcfox I agree. Client is extensively using declarative rollup summary tool for calculating rollups and it is stemming from dlrs package and not in my control.

Comment: @sfdcfox I see others also ran into same issue and there is no solution yet : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209703/how-to-rethrow-dmlexceptions-as-aurahandledexceptions-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you can't control other people's code, you can control your own. You should be able to do this:

```
Database.SaveResult result = Database.delete(oppObj, false);
if(!result.isSuccess()) {
  throw new AuraHandledException(result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
}
```

You will no longer get DmlException messages, but instead get a nice interface to render an error with. If you still need to contend with *other* types of errors (e.g. a NullPointerException), you can wrap up the entire thing and rethrow:

```
try {
  Database.SaveResult result = Database.delete(oppObj, false);
  if(!result.isSuccess()) {
    throw new AuraHandledException(result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but It didn't work. Here is the video showing the change I made as per your suggestion and the result: https://vimeo.com/281628694  If you have time, you can take a look at the complete code I uploaded on gist : https://gist.github.com/sfdcnoob/4c686babb21d82e65d2fea11e3288cae Thanks again.

Comment: @javanoob That's not the experience I get... When I installed your code, I get "55invalid reference id" when testing. You might be dealing with a caching issue.

Comment: Did you update the hard-coded ids in the controller and trigger? "55Invalid reference Id" seems to be because of that. Thanks for trying my code.

Comment: @javanoob Huh. Yeah, after updating, it works that way now. Realistically, then, I don't think there's a foolproof way of doing it except to fix the code that's misbehaving. As far as your regex, I'm guessing that there's some newlines/alternative whitespace that's messing your regex up. Maybe: `:\\s+\\[\\]\\s+.*` might work better?

Comment: Thanks. The regex you suggested worked and it is not showing stacktrace of line numbers. I see an open issue(https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues/301) on DLRS github, requesting for `allOrNone` flag to false. In conclusion, I can get it the way I want, only if I have access to the trigger that is doing the actual DML on the failing record. Thank you again for taking time to look into this.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need to parse the message with regex. The `getDmlMessage(i)` method gives you the 'pretty' message output without the stack trace details.

In the example below, I created a validation rule on the Account object that throws an exception if the Account Number field has been changed.

> Error Condition Formula: ISCHANGED( AccountNumber )
>
> Error Message: Cannot change account number

---

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" 
                access="global" 
                controller="q226338Controller">

    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>
    <button onclick="{!c.updateAccount}">Update Account Number</button>

</aura:component>
```

---

Controller

```
({
    updateAccount: function (component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.updateAccountNumber");
        action.setCallback(this, function (result) {
            if (result.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
                console.log('success?');
            }
            if (result.getState() == 'ERROR') {
                component.find('notifLib')
                    .showToast({
                        "title": "Error!",
                        "message": result.getError()[0].message
                    });
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

---

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class q226338Controller {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateAccountNumber() {
        String newNumber = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(Math.random() * 2000));

        Account a = new Account(Id = 'hardcoded value', 
                               AccountNumber = newNumber);

        try {
            update a;
        } catch (DmlException ex) {
            throw new AurahandledException(ex.getDmlMessage(0));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new AurahandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:
[image]

The pretty error message output can also be seen here:
[Built-In Exceptions and Common Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_builtin.htm)

Comment: It looks similar to my problem but it is slightly different. In my case, DML began in Apex controller but exception occured in trigger because of that `getDmlMessage(0)` is returning complete stacktrace. I found similar unanswered question here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209703/how-to-rethrow-dmlexceptions-as-aurahandledexceptions-right

Answer (score 2):

I think that simpliest solution will be creating customer label and placing it in the AuraHandledException.

```
 throw new AuraHandledException(Label.YourException);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am confused as why my regex approach also not working. Do you see anything wrong there?